# Moving from Java to Android

Tags: java, android, mobile, mobile-application

For my final year project, I am doing some Android development making a mobile app and a website for it.  I've been a Java programmer for 3 years and know my way round it.  One thing that has got me confused is it's taken me a while to get used to this platform with Swing being replaced with some fancy XML.

Now, apart from the GUI, is everything else pretty much the same i.e. File I/O and Threading?

Also, am I also correct in using Log.d(TAG,text); as an alternative to System.out.println() ?

Answer (score 3):

File I/O and Threading are Java Standard Edition 1.6. Android also added some facilities for threading like AsyncTask. Log is the android logger. i stays for info, d for debug, w for warning e for error...

Answer (score 3):

I'll say shortly what Android has added on its own:

- Modular application model
- GUI framework
- Resources management with automatic adjustment depending on configuration
- Inter-process communication model
- Application data storage through settings and databases
- Logging and testing framework (the latter is based on JUnit 3).

This is the list of the most essential things you will have to learn when programming for Android. The basics are derived from Java SE, which includes working with the file system and threads.